# How to correctly specify the wsdl location in JAX-WS?

Tags: java, wsdl, jax-ws

I received a code recently for a JAX-WS client application, where I saw that a wsdl was specified locally in order to build the endpoint. But it was specified statically, and I do not think this is right.

```
static {
    URL url = null;
   try {
      url = new URL("file:/home/user/work/src/proj/myproject.wsdl");
    } catch (MalformedURLException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    WSDL_LOCATION = url;
}
```

This is not the correct way to do it is it? What is another way to specify the location of this wsdl?

Comment: Mostly webservice container creates there own wsdl on basis of implementation. You can get that wsdl directly from endpoint url like this -> http://endpointURL?wsdl

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can place the wsdl in your classpath and refer to it as below:

```
URL url = ClassLoader.getResource("myproject.wsdl");
```

Or

```
URL url = ClassLoader.getSystemResource("myproject.wsdl");
```

Answer (score 2):

There are two possible ways:

- Add the WSDL as a resource of your project. It will then be embedded inside the final jar and you can access it with [`Class.getResource(String name)`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Class.html#getResource-java.lang.String-).
- Point to the WSDL hosted by the web server. It will typically be of the form `http://example.com/MyWebService?WSDL` (note the `?WSDL` at the end).

Comment: For Class.getResource the resource should be in the same package as of Class; not in a resources folder(configured as source)